# Get a popup instead of an iframe when using getElementById

Tags: openlayers

I have a map (openlayers) that gives me an iframe of attribute data when a pixel is clicked/ queried. How would I go about having a nice popup window instead of an iframe? My code for the query is:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
        var url = towns.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) {
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
              '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
        }
      });
```

The 'info' is from

```
 <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: This isn't really a GIS SE question. This is a primarily html/css and javascript question so belongs on [overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) If you mean a [browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript). Other than that you'd need to design custom CSS/HTML to have in map popups/modules.

Comment: I think this could also be what you need http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

Comment: I did actually post this on overflow but they didn't understand the spatial component. That example with the coordinates popup- how could it be adjusted to display attribute data instead of coordinates?